# Mikrotik NAT rules order

Tags: nat

I have Mikrotik router, which has WAN connected at ether1. Now I need to set up NAT to send TCP and UDP on port 25565 to IP 192.168.2.42 and every other port (all protocols) to 192.168.2.41

This is my current configuration:

[image: Mikrotik configuration]

What I am looking for is to descrease priority of rule #1 and increase priority of rule #2 and #3.

How do I do this? If there are no priorities, what is the correct way of this implementation?

Comment: I believe the rules are run in order. You could try to change the order of the rules.

Comment: @RonMaupin - Yes, I am sure that they are. What I am asking is how to change the order. Drag & drop does not work.

Comment: I'm no expert on this device, but I think you may need to delete and recreate them in the correct order.

Comment: Eh ... ok, I will try it, but in firewall tab is ordering done with drag & drop.

Comment: You wrote that drag and drop doesn't work with this.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes, it does not (just in firewall, I am setting NAT). And by the way, the recreation worked. Thanks - can you add this as an answer?

Comment: OK. I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are tested in order. It appears that drag-and-drop does not work with this, and it seems that you need to delete the rules and recreate them in the correct order.